# Tag request for academics and scholars

Tags: discussion, tags

When questions request answers with Christian scholars and academics as the context from which they should be answered:

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/55316/what-does-james-117-mean-by-perfect-gift

[Do any Christian scholars contrast Islamic eschatology with Christian eschatology?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/52826/do-any-christian-scholars-contrast-islamic-eschatology-with-christian-eschatolog?s=1|0.9368)

[Have Christian Scholars been forced to use BCE and CE instead of AD and BC?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/55044/have-christian-scholars-been-forced-to-use-bce-and-ce-instead-of-ad-and-bc?s=3|0.8266)

[What explanations have scholars proposed for the rejection of the Didache from the Canon?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/42847/what-explanations-have-scholars-proposed-for-the-rejection-of-the-didache-from-t?s=4|0.7820)

They're commonly ambiguously tagged.  (My question probably being the worst of the bunch).  Can we retag these puppies so we can find them easier and help people out who want to edit their questions to ask for this as a framework, but don't see a tag to match what they're looking for?

Answer (score 3):

At least at first blush, I think part of the reason we don't (and probably shouldn't) have a tag for these is that "christian-scholars" is not a meaningful class that identifies a perspective or maps out a scope. These questions are ambiguously tagged because they are themselves ambiguous. Adding a tag would be a band-aid on broken femur.

At best what these questions could be interpreted to read is that they are looking for more scholarly academic themed resources rather that pastoral or lay resources. This in itself isn't a taxonomy and is rather redundant as that level of resources are ideally what we'd like to see on *all* questions.

At worst creating such a tag would only encourage more ambiguous unscoped questions with clever disguises whose fatal flaws won't show up until after a few contradictory answers start showing up.

Comment: See [Are critical scholars a scope?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6208/6071) for the difficulties in trying to use academia as a scope.